# ToString() doesn't work

Tags: tostring

I want to get int parameter and save it to playerprefs and then get it and change it to string and display as string, but when I use ToString(); there is error: Cannot implicitly convert type `string' to`int' for a=b;
C# unity
    public int a;
    public string b;

```
 {
            car = GameObject.Find ("mastergame").GetComponent<master> ().carr;
            if (car == 1) {
                busted = GameObject.Find ("1").GetComponent<ruchauta1> ().busted;
                gameover = GameObject.Find ("1").GetComponent<ruchauta1> ().gameover;
                if (gameover == false && busted == false) {
                    scoree.text = "" + score;   
                }
                if (gameover == true || busted == true) {
                    if(score>bestscore){
                        bestscore=score;
                        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("bestscore",bestscore);}
                    score=0;
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score",score);
                }               
            } else {
                busted = GameObject.Find ("Audi").GetComponent<ruchauta> ().busted;
                gameover = GameObject.Find ("Audi").GetComponent<ruchauta> ().gameover;
                if (gameover == false && busted == false) {
                    scoree.text = "" + score;

                }
                if (gameover == true || busted == true) {
                    if(score>bestscore){
                        bestscore=score;
                        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("bestscore",bestscore);
                        a=PlayerPrefs.GetInt("bestscore",bestscore);}
                    score=0;
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score",score);              
                }
            }
            a.ToString ();
            a = b;
            bestscoree.text = b;
        }
        void Score(){
            car = GameObject.Find ("mastergame").GetComponent<master> ().carr;

            if (car == 1) {
                busted = GameObject.Find ("1").GetComponent<ruchauta1> ().busted;
                gameover = GameObject.Find ("1").GetComponent<ruchauta1> ().gameover;
                if (gameover == false && busted == false) {
                    score+=5;
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score",score);              
                }

            } else {
                busted = GameObject.Find ("Audi").GetComponent<ruchauta> ().busted;
                gameover = GameObject.Find ("Audi").GetComponent<ruchauta> ().gameover;
                if (gameover == false && busted == false) {
                    score+=5;
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("score",score);
                }
            }
```

Comment: What platform and language library are you using here? What looks suspicious to me is the `a.ToString ();` followed immediately by `a = b;`. Assuming `a.ToSTring ();` actually changes `a`, whatever changes are made would be overwritten by `a = b`.

Comment: if i delete a=b, and write bestscoree.text = a; there is still this error.

Answer (score 0):

`ToString()` creates a string representation of an object and returns that value. It does not (or should not) change the value/contents of the object it is operating on and it certainly does not change the type of the object. So the line with `a.ToString()` likely results in no change.

Since `b` is a string (based upon the error you gave) and presumably contains a string representation of an integer, if you want to set the value of `a` with the value of `b`, you must first convert `b` to an integer. I'm not sure what language this is but that is typically done with one of several methods. Some examples:

```
a = Convert.ToInt(b);
a = int.Parse(b);
a = Int32.Parse(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

toString itself does not convert a's type, what you should do is:

```
String newString = a.toString()
```

after that, you can play with your newString.